# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: python, gtk

My pygtk program writes this warning to stderr:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

[libcanberra](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/libcanberra/) seems to be a library for sound.

My program does not use any sound. Is there a way to disable this error message?

Installing libcanberra is not a solution.

Comment: I'm guessing something in your operating system adds "canberra-gtk-module" to `$GTK_MODULES` and GTK is doing as it's told: tries to load the specified module.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" Unable to connect to dbus - Sublime text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058926/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-unable-to-connect-to-db)

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by running

```
 sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*
```

you can try it.